# Library or algorithm to convert a HOCON string to a valid json string

Tags: java, json, scala, yaml, hocon

I am limited to using `hocon` for our config files in our java app's.
My problem is I cannot change the format but I now need to store it in another backend that only accepts flat `yaml` files.

Example `app.conf` file:

```
play {
  http {
    port = 9000
    port = ${?HTTP_PORT}
    secret.key = "secretKey"
    secret.key = ${?APPLICATION_SECRET}
    errorHandler = Example.handler.ErrorHandler
  }
}
```

Attempt 1: Read and parse `hocon` file with TypesafeConfig:

```
final ConfigRenderOptions renderOptions = ConfigRenderOptions.defaults()
          .setOriginComments( false )
          .setJson( true )
          .setComments( false );


// Render mergedConfig: Config
String jsonFromHocon = mergedConfig.root().render( renderOptions );
final JsonNode jsonNodeTree = mapper.readTree( jsonFromHocon );
```

There are 2 problems when this happens:

- The `mapper.readTree` will throw an error because the 2nd entry of `play.http.port` is not a number and it is not quoted, `${?HTTP_PORT}` is the literal value; I want to preserve the features of hocon which include env replacements if the value is not quoted.
- Even if the values were converted into legal values - when it is converted to json it is overwritten with the last value. This breaks feature parity with hocon.

Any ideas on how to take advantage of typeSafe configs ability to print out conf to semi-valid json.

I cannot use a packaged json parser unless I am able to manipulate the result of the values.
I googled a bit on how to custom read values but I do not believe it is possible at this time.

expected output:
Add quotes to all values and append the value `__replace__` to all keys with duplicate keys and have the env vars

```
play {
  http {
    port = "9000"
    port__replace__ = "${?HTTP_PORT}"
    secret.key = "\"secretKey\""
    secret.key__replace__ = "${?APPLICATION_SECRET}"
    errorHandler = "Example.handler.ErrorHandler"
  }
}
```

Please prove me wrong! Or suggest an idea!
Is there a hocon format to yaml format parser out there?

Comment: You're going back and forth rendering to json and to yaml in your question. How exactly do these two come into play? Also, can you give the expected outcome for the snippet?

Comment: @Martijn Added what I want as the result

Comment: Your expected output isn't valid yaml or json